# Taking screenshots on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Anybody please tell me on how to take screenshot just like in the picture below

[image]

Thank you

Comment: From eclipse->go to project res layout->chose your project xml->graphic layout->right click your layout->select Export Screenshot... option

Comment: i want to add mobile image to screenshot

Comment: For that you have to edit your image manually

Comment: Is there any android enumerator for that ...

Comment: Android emulators wont show the particular device,it will show only the layout as per the screen size.

Comment: use this web-tool for framing your app screenshot to real mobile device, it's free http://www.appdemostore.com/frameapp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use android **official device art generator** .

You need to follow some step mention in below link :

https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/device-art.html

Answer (score 1):

For Making Same like this image .. first of all you have to take snap shot of your application. Then fit that snapshot to Below image.
Using [this Software](http://www.photoscape.org/ps/main/download.php)

[image]

And then add text over that..

Finally it look like as you want..

Thanks